# iterating through xml works fine in FF but not in IE using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
(function(){

var xmlString="<Family><people><title>News for Golf</title></people><people><title>News for NBA</title></people></Family>"

$(xmlString).find('people').each(function(){
alert($(this).html());
});

})(jQuery);
```

The above code runs fine on FF and gives

```
<title>News for Golf</title>
<title>News for NBA</title>
```

but not in IE, can anyone suggest what is the problem for IE, I need the same output as above.

Also, if possible what exactly i want is

```
 <people><title>News for Golf</title></people>
 <people><title>News for NBA</title></people>
```

thanks,
bond

Answer (score 2):

You're not parsing the XML into a format that Jquery will use correctly.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

You should do something like this:

```
var xmlstring = '<Family><people><title>News for Golf</title></people><people><title>News  for NBA</title></people></Family>'​​​​​​​​;
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlstring);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
var $people = $xml.find('people');
$.each($people,function(index,person){
    //Here person refers to the person node of the XML
});
```

Comment: addition: if the OP wants <people> instead of <title> in the .each loop use this code: $("<div>").append(person).html();

Comment: still not able to get the each person node as given above.

Comment: .html() on the person node will not work. It would technically print out <title>News for Golf</title> since that's the html content of the person node. It won't however, because .html() can't be called on an XML object. 

Mr Bond, do you explicitly need to keep the XML in XML string format? You could use $(xmlstring).contents() but this won't work in IE (it doesn't like inline xml). 

You can always rebuild the xml yourself by putting this in the foreach:

    $('div').append('<people><title>'+$(this).text()+'</title></people>');